# Android ListView scrolls to top after visibility change of an item

Tags: android, listview

I've have a listview with some items inside it.
For some of these items, when the users clicks on a button, the buttons is hidden and a status label is showed.

This works fine, but the problem is that the listview scrolls to the top everytime I change the visibility of some item inside a listview.

Any suggestion to avoid this?
I want the listview to stay where it is.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877848/android-listview-scrolls-back-to-top-on-update

Comment: post your code please!