# Add New Item to ListView For Implement Endless List In Android

Tags: android, listview

In my list I wanna Implement endless list. for now when I scroll down and receive to fifth item of list, new data load but data not add to end of list, it clear all item of list and then show.

How append new item to end of list.
Notice that I'm using  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  but still don't work for me.

here my  EndlessScrollListener class:

```
public class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
       // private int currentPage = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (myList.getLastVisiblePosition() >= myList.getCount() - visibleThreshold) {
                    cpage++;
                    new sendpage(cpage).execute();
                    if (isOnline()) {
                        requestData("http://192.168.1.3/android_login_api/include/get_post.php");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    updateDisplay();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }
        }
```

and my updateDisplay function:

```
protected void updateDisplay() {
     adapter = new MyCustommAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, postList);

       // adapter = new MyCustommAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, postList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

my requestData() function:

```
 private void requestData(String uri) {


        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(uri,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        postList = PostJSONParser.parseFeed(response);

                        updateDisplay();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

PostJSONParser class:

```
public class PostJSONParser {


    public static List<Post> parseFeed(String content){


        JSONArray ar = null;
        try {
            ar = new JSONArray(content);
            List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
            for (int j =0; j<ar.length(); j++){
                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(j);
                Post post = new Post();

                post.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
                post.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                post.setContent(obj.getString("content"));
                post.setCreated_at(obj.getString("created_at"));
                post.setUrl_image(obj.getString("url_image"));
                postList.add(post);

            }
            return postList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

notice that requestData() function get new item using volley.

Any Idea how Implement it?

Comment: In your requestData(...) function are you updaing postList variable ? because I think you are overwriting the (ArrayList) postList with new data instead of just adding postList.add(newItem);

Comment: I'm added requestData() function.

Comment: This is the problem  postList = PostJSONParser.parseFeed(response); this line is overwriting this variable with new data , so your previous data is getting lost

Comment: I updated the answer can you try the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** Here's the solution Create a new `ArrayList` variable that will hold new data Temporarily and then add it this ArrayList to the original **use ArrayList everwhere**

First where you have declare the variable postList make sure it is like this

```
 ArrayList<Post> postList=new ArrayList<Post>(); //and make this variable global
```

Second in your parseFeed function

```
public class PostJSONParser {


public static ArrayList<Post> parseFeed(String content){


    JSONArray ar = null;
    try {
        ar = new JSONArray(content);
        ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
        for (int j =0; j<ar.length(); j++){
            JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(j);
            Post post = new Post();

            post.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            post.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
            post.setContent(obj.getString("content"));
            post.setCreated_at(obj.getString("created_at"));
            post.setUrl_image(obj.getString("url_image"));
            postList.add(post);

        }
        return postList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
}
```

And finally inside your requestData() function

```
private void requestData(String uri) {


    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(uri,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    ArrayList<Post> tempList=new ArrayList<Post>();
                    tempList = PostJSONParser.parseFeed(response);
                    postList.addAll(tempList);

                    updateDisplay();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Make sure you use ArrayList everwhere

Comment: I added to requestData() function but got an error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can you try this postList.addAll(PostJSONParser.parseFeed(response)); and remove all the new line that i just added just use this one line

Comment: I add parser. I try last code bu again java.lang.NullPointerException  error on that line

Comment: I thin I found some thing. the problem is I use both first time and for updating list just one code. I create same function with different name and use your code. it's work but when load new item it's go to first item. how fix it?

Comment: This is another problem , maybe this will work [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877848/android-listview-scrolls-back-to-top-on-update)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you question fully, however when trying to create an "endless list" I have always found that the best structure to use is an ArrayList, it has preset functions for adding and deleting data that I found very useful.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I know there is so much tutorial out there but, If you can tell me how implement in my code