# How to move listview on top of data loaded from server in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` which contains data from a server. Scenario is something like that initial 5 data are shown in `listview`. When I scroll download `listview` add 5 more data from server. What I want when new data load in `listview` want to move `listview` on top of new data that was loaded. How can I do that?

Comment: try this it work [listview scrolls back to top on update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11932504/5080100)

Comment: see intial i have 5 data in listview when I scroll to bottom send server rrequest and load five more data ,,,here I want lisview move to top of five data that are loaded from server instead of preious five data .